# Invoke Windows service from Oracle AFTER INSERT Trigger

Tags: windows, oracle, service, triggers

How can we invoke windows service (or) dll file from Oracle AFTER INSERT Trigger

Any suggestion will be highly appreciated

Best Regards,

Answer (score 1):

You can run OS commands from plsql.
This can be done as described in this [AskTom post](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:2155105300346643982) or [this](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:952229840241#2717585194628) (preior to 11g)

So, if you can call the service or dll from a script, then this might work

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I wounder if is it possible to check the Oracle AFTER INSERT Trigger from C# using ODP.NET connectivity

Comment: What do you mean *check the Oracle AFTER INSERT Trigger* ?

Comment: I mean will it be possible that an external NET application connected to Oracle database verifies after insert trigger whether fired or not so that based on it an appropriate action can be executed at external application level

Comment: Haven't tried it, but what if the trigger itself will execute the external application as a command ? What exactly is the need ?

Comment: The idea is to invoke a specific task whenever a new record is inserted into the Oracle table, I believe the AFTER INSERT trigger will be sufficient as notification of new record insertion, the only part left is invoking the external application

Comment: It doesn't "feal right" but as I wrote in prev comment - you can invoke it from the trigger by using the methods in the links in the answer...