# Invoke c# Windows service from Oracle AFTER INSERT Trigger

Tags: c#, oracle

How can we `invoke c# windows service` (or) `dll` file from Oracle `AFTER INSERT Trigger`

Any suggestion will be highly appreciated

Best Regards,

Comment: What have you tried? Please ask a specific question and provide code samples. Here's a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14918695/invoke-windows-service-from-oracle-after-insert-trigger

Answer (score 1):

As a rule, a windows service is not designed to be invoked upon a specific request, it should be running continuously in the background.

In order to get Oracle DB to do something then you will first need a trigger on your table which monitors for inserts.

Then, this should called a java stored procedure.  This stored procedure can then send a message on a message bus which can be received by your service and processed.

See:
[Sending a JMS Message from Oracle Database on DML Event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17599155/sending-a-jms-message-from-oracle-database-on-dml-event)

[Oracle: Java stored procedure sending JMS Message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7000003/oracle-java-stored-procedure-sending-jms-message)

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14257/jm_point.htm

Another method is to get the java stored procedure to call an external program

Comment: i need when my oracle database table is changed then the trigger should fired a mail from c# window service

Comment: That's not how a trigger works.  A trigger is fired when something happens on a database table, it only exists in the database.  Use the procedure I suggest above to get your windows service to do whatever you need to do, which might be to send a message/event to another program.

Comment: how to invoke a c# window service in oracle trigger when my database table a row inserted or update

Comment: yes that's the point when my database table record changed or inserted then a trigger is fired a mail from c# window service

Comment: is it possible?

Comment: No.  A trigger exists only IN the oracle database.  If you want to send an email then there are other ways, such as this:  http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Send_mail_from_PL/SQL

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue by making the Oracle trigger call a WebApi service using `utl_http`.  This way the "service" can sit waiting for requests and the trigger is light touch.  Here is a sample of my trigger:

```
declare 
  content varchar2(4000);
  req utl_http.req;
  res utl_http.resp;
  url varchar2(4000) := 'http://server.com/api/Function';
begin

  content := '{ "Message": "Hello" }';
  req := utl_http.begin_request(url, 'POST',' HTTP/1.1');
  utl_http.set_header(req, 'user-agent', 'mozilla/4.0'); 
  utl_http.set_header(req, 'content-type', 'application/json'); 
  utl_http.set_header(req, 'Content-Length', length(content));

  utl_http.write_text(req, content);
  res := utl_http.get_response(req);
  if res.status_code <> 200 then
    dbms_output.put_line(res.reason_phrase);
  end if;
  utl_http.end_response(res);
end;
```

You can put whatever logic you want into the WebApi endpoint.  If you really want a windows service, you could have the trigger write to something like RabbitMQ and have the service consume the exchange queue.

Comment: ok        but how to create a oracle trigger for invoke c# window servie? that automatically fired mail when my database record change or a new row inserted in the table......................

Comment: The code above will fire when a change or insert happens (as long as its created as a trigger), and it will send a message to the URL listed - this service could easily send a mail you just need to fill the content with whatever you want to send, and enable the endpoint.

Comment: @ Dominic......the above code you have provided me that code how to use in a oracle trigger and service

Comment: Not sure I understand your comment, I explained in answer to your original question for a suggestion - mine is to call a WebApi service from the trigger using the code above - I wasn't sure I needed to post an example of a WebApi endpoint?  Good luck with your solution

Comment: CAN I USE HERE MY WEBSERVICE URL `url varchar2(4000) := 'http://server.com/api/Function';`